# scutil does not change the resolv.conf when the primaryservice is forticlientsslvpn on macOS Mojave

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, macos-mojave, fortigate

I use the `version 6.0.8_149` of `forticlient`. 
In the configuration of the forticlient, you can tell him to execute a script at `on connect`. what is interesting is that I could (with the previous version 5) inject my script that modifies the name servers via `dnsutil`.

except that since the update to version 6, `dnsutil` no longer modifies nameservers

I manually tested via `sudo scutil`:

```
$sudo scutil
password: *****
> get State:/Network/Service/forticlientsslvpn/DNS
> d.show
<dictionary> {
  ServerAddresses : <array> {
    0 : xxx.xx.xxx.xx
    1 : yyy.yy.yyy.y
    2 : 127.0.0.1
  }
}
> d.remove ServerAddresses
> d.add ServerAddresses * 127.0.0.1 xxx.xx.xxx.xx
> set State:/Network/Service/forticlientsslvpn/DNS
> quit

Still got:

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver xxx.xx.xxx.xx
nameserver yyy.yy.yyy.y
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

as you can see, the `resolv.conf` does not change at all.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I thank you in advance for this.